# Inappbrowser callback

Tags: facebook, cordova, sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

I have tried to call back after login in facebook using inappbrowser. But it doesnt work to check the email,name etc.Here my code

**Inappbrowser calling**

```
function onDeviceReady(){   
     var my_client_id = FBkey,
     my_redirect_uri = "http://www.fastabuy.com/index.php",
     my_type = "user_agent",
     my_display = "touch";

     var authorize_url = FBgraphapiurl+"/oauth/authorize?";
     authorize_url += "client_id=" + my_client_id;
     authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + my_redirect_uri;
     authorize_url += "&display=" + my_display;
     authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream,email,user_likes";
     isfir = "true";

     var ref = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function facebookLocChanged() {
         facebookLoc(my_redirect_uri)
     });
}
```

Method for checking call back

```
  function facebookLoc(loc){
     if (loc.indexOf("http://www.fastabuy.com/index.php?") > -1){
       alert(loc.indexOf)
     }
  }
```

How to check when the url `loc.indexOf>-1` to close the inappbrowser. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: just now i finished login with facebook task in my app.. see my answer that should solve your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You need to use `loadstart` event in InAppBrowser for checking redirected page.

2) After successful login use `close` method for closing InAppBrowser.

3) When you call `facebookLoc` function in callback, you should watch out for scope and i am using `me` variable to solve this problem.

```
onFacebookLogin: function() {

    var me = this;
    var appInBrowser = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

    appInBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
         me.facebookLoc(event.url,appInBrowser);
    });    
}

facebookLoc : function(loc,appInBrowser) {
   if (loc.indexOf("www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html") > -1){
         alert('Login success');
         appInBrowser.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: how to know when the url reaches redirecting url

Comment: @Fazil i didn't get you.. for what you are asking ?

Comment: i to call that onFacebookLogin fuction

Answer (score 4):

Here a sample https://github.com/raulduran/facebook-cordova

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.onFacebookLogin();
},

onFacebookLogin: function() {

    var authorize_url  = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
        authorize_url += "client_id=" + appId;
        authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl;
        authorize_url += "&display=touch";
        authorize_url += "&response_type=token";
        authorize_url += "&type=user_agent";

    if(permissions !== '') {
        authorize_url += "&scope=" + permissions;
    }

    var userDenied = false;
    var appInBrowser = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=no');

    appInBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(location) {

        if (location.url.indexOf("access_token") !== -1) {
            // Success
            var access_token = location.url.match(/access_token=(.*)$/)[1].split('&expires_in')[0];
            window.localStorage.setItem('facebook_accessToken', access_token);
            appInBrowser.close();
        }

        if (location.url.indexOf("error_reason=user_denied") !== -1) {
            // User denied
            userDenied = true;
            window.localStorage.setItem('facebook_accessToken', null);
            appInBrowser.close();
        }
    });
}
```