# Communication between popup and opener from distinct domains

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth-2.0, local, same-origin-policy

I am writing an app using Phonegap (js, css and html on local filesystem) and I would like to get an oauth token from it. 
So I open a popup to display our authentication server page. After the login process, it is redirected to the page I mentioned providing the code in its URL.

It appears the redirect page can't be a local file ("Not allowed to load local resource: file://..."). 
If I redirect to a page accessed using http I have an issue with "same origin policy" (SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a cross-origin frame), and I can't access the main page (on local file system) from the popup using window.opener.

How could I communicate the code from the popup to a local file (Storage, webSocket, anything else)?

Comment: I've had the same problem, but in a different context. My workaround was to attempt to communicate back to the main browser window that authentication is complete, using `window.opener.postMessage`. This works perfectly fine in normal borwsers, but Cordova's inAppBrowser does not expose the window.opener object so no dice.

Comment: This work-around seems to address that issue: http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser

Comment: Ultimately, I found using the custom `loadstart` event to be a simpler solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18633515/2155068.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use InAppBrowser to navigate to this authentication page? (See more info here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).

I am not certain on how your page returns the data, but I am sure there is a way you can return the generated data from InAppBrowser through to your app.

Comment: The issue ("Not allowed to load local resource") doesn't happen when I try to navigate to the authentication page. It happens after that (step 4 in this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization.html)), when the login process on this authentication page succeeds and tries to redirect (a http redirection) to a local file. That redirection to a local file appears to be forbidden by browser built-in security design. Actually, the code is given to the page through its url.